# How to email multiple rows from sqlite3 query with python email widget

Tags: python, email, sqlite

I have made an application in python with tkinter GUI.
In this application I have a button and when I click it I want to email certain records from my database to a customer using the standard email library from python. However I seem to be able to only send 1 record...

Am I overlooking something?

```
def Send_OC_Worksheet_Mail(self, event):
    fromaddr = "my email address"
    toaddr = "customer email address"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "my subject"
    Send_Jobs_List_Qry = (c.execute('SELECT Job_Description, Job_Date FROM Jobs WHERE Worksheet_Mailed=?', (0,  ))).fetchall()
    for Send_Jobs_List_Row in Send_Jobs_List_Qry:
        Job_Descr = str(Send_Jobs_List_Row[0])
        Job_Date = str(Send_Jobs_List_Row[1])
        Job_Body = (Job_Date+':'+Job_Descr+'\n')
        body = Job_Body
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "password")
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: This code sends zero records. Is this really the code that you're using, especially the line `msg.attach` and the one below?

Comment: Hi, sorry the MIMEText was next to the msg.attach (this is also how it is in my code)  must've somehow messed that up when writing my question

Comment: The problem seems to be solved. I pressed enter after the msg.attach line, creating an empty line and that seems to work...